# Closed questions which get a lot of upvotes

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I noticed that there are a bunch of closed questions which have a lot of people voting on them, and answering them.

I don't understand it, if SO is all about the community monitoring the site then why do the questions the community is interested in get closed? Most of the questions of that type are the "What book should I read?" questions (I might be wrong, there might be some other type of questions I haven't encountered yet) for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570/what-is-the-best-quick-read-python-book-out-there) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528364/books-on-good-programming-practises). Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) one with a really huge activity. It is obvious that there are people interested in the answers.

Why doesn't SO change the policy?

Why are those questions still get closed?

Comment: Upvotes don't mean they're on topic.

Comment: @ColeJohnson yes, that's the point, they get upvoted because there are people interested in getting the answer and\or they consider the question a good\useful one.

Comment: @alex - at one stage, they *were good* questions. Since then, the definition of a good post on [so] has changed, but still some of the older posts contain good content. The questions are closed according to the current rules, but they stick around for *historical significance*, as mentioned in the locked notice.

Comment: @AndrewC not exaclty, there isn't an answer for the "What book should I read?" story.

Comment: @Lix thank you for clarifying some stuff.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality) first.  Go ahead, we'll wait.

Done? Great.  So how does this relate to your question?  Simple: *Popular doesn't necessarily mean good.*  Popularity certainly doesn't necessarily equate with fulfilling our mission, which is to provide quality answers to programming questions.  Book review questions certainly do not fulfill that mission.

To prove my point, I am including this completely irrelevant picture of a cute kitten. Now watch the upvotes roll in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Great kitten pic.

Comment: -1 because I'm a dog man.

Comment: Mmmmm, tiny turkey...

Comment: Sorry, it's really important to the point in the argument that the kitten is very cute. The second kitten wasn't as cute. This new kitten is very cute. I'm afraid the small roast poultry had to go too, sorry @ErnestFriedman-Hill. I decided not to rollback to version 1, as Robert had clearly decided that the first kitten from the cute kitten Google search wasn't cute enough.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Liar. You love cats and the vote count is proof ;)

Comment: @AsheeshR He could have retracted his downvote because of the roast poultry.

Comment: I don't follow the crowd. I'm an iconoclast, a rebel! Down arrow, here I co-- *...so very cute...*

Comment: Mmmmm bite size...

Comment: The damn kitten looked hungry.

Comment: +1 [kitty](http://xkcd.com/231/)!

Comment: On a more serious note, I'm now contemplating adding an irrelevant kitty pic on *all* my Meta posts to attract upvotes.

Comment: So goddamned hungry now.

Comment: @AsheeshR The edit to this answer that changed the cat to poultry is exactly why edits which change the meaning of a post are not acceptable! ;)